# PHP MySQL throwing error around anonymous variables in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

When I run my prepared statement, I get the following error:

> Error: INSERT INTO articles (`url`, `headline`, `pubDate`, `source`, `image_loc`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 6

Here's the code that seems to be throwing the error:

```
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName (`url`, 
                            `headline`, 
                            `pubDate`, 
                            `source`, 
                            `image_loc`) 
                VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        // MySQLi connection, binds variables to prevent injection, executes
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $url, $headline, $pubDate, $source, $image_loc);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Edit: Here's what I'm setting up as my connection in a separate file. It works in the sense that everything is being saved ... I'm just still throwing an error.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "news";
$tableName = "articles";

$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$connection) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Edit again: This is the code that was put in to check on the success of the insert, though I'm guessing this may be the root of the problem (but I'm not experienced enough to understand why):

```
if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection) . "<br>";
        }
```

Comment: I think you need a space after `VALUES` and before the braket.

Comment: What's the output if you add this line: `print_r($stmt); die();` before `$stmt->execute();`?

Comment: Odd. Looks fine to me. Is that your *exact* code? Can you take it down to a minimal complete example (including setting up `$tableName`, etc) that still shows the problem? That looks like exactly the error you'd get if you were executing the statement without binding the variables.

Comment: (Also, specifically, what type is `$connection`? How did you create it?)

Comment: Unbelievable as it may be, can you try the suggestion made by @worldofjr - I distinctly remember having exact same issues with MySQL prior to 5.4. Simply put a space after keyword `VALUES` and try again.

Comment: Make sure there are no hidden characters,just rewrite the query as it is by hand

Comment: Try to output the correct error, `$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));`

Comment: The space after VALUES was taken out as I was experimenting with the issue. Adding it back did not help. And yes, that is my exact code. In a connection file, I'm setting up a database connection via a mysqli connection. I'll edit and add that code. Though it's probably worth mentioning that even with this error, it is saving the correct info to the database.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you running?

Comment: Running MySQL version 5.5.42. Running PHP version 5.6.10 via MAMP.

Comment: "even with this error, it is saving the correct info to the database" <-- I can't see how that could possibly be true if you're getting a syntax error. The statement simply won't be executed. Where exactly is this error report coming from?

Comment: It's definitely saving, though looking through this code I've pieced together from examples today, it actually seems to be being printed by the latest update I added above.

Comment: Are you using that `$sql` variable somewhere else in your code? It looks like your prepared statement executes but something else tries to execute what's in `$sql`. That looks like a good potential cause to me.

Comment: The only time $sql is being created or called are the two times above - first in creating the INSERT line, next in the snippet that checks for success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code:

```
if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection) . "<br>";
}
```

...uses [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). That is actually another way of executing a query, only unlike `execute()` it doesn't use bound parameters. It just sends the query to the database, question marks and all, thus creating your error.

If you want to check for an error, you should check the result of your `execute()` statement when you run it, not perform a further query. Replace your `$stmt->execute()` line with something like this, to execute the query and also test for success:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

Comment: So to ask the stupidest question - the error wasn't in the original code, it was in what I thought was checking it for success? If I take that out, it does not throw an error. Is there an easy way to check for insertion success in what I've got?

Comment: @Chris I've updated my answer. Yes, basically, your original "error checking" code was actually trying to execute the query again, only without the bound parameters. All you need to do is check the return value of the `execute()` statement to find out if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection) . "<br>";
}
```

You should use the `mysqli::$affected_rows` property, like this;

```
if ($connection->affected_rows > 0) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error() . "<br>";
}
```